# Writing filenames with special characters python

Tags: python

I need to save file names with certain special characters, this is an example: `IMAGE - Topčider.jpeg`. I manage to save the file correctly with this code:

```
image_req = requests.get(image)
    with open(title_for_file, "wb") as f:
        f.write(image_req.content)
```

However, when I open the file with the pyexiv2 module it raises this error:

`IMAGE - Topčider.jpeg: Failed to open the data source: No such file or directory (errno = 2)`

If I look in the directory, the file is in there only as `IMAGE - .jpeg`, so my question is how can I resolve this error? I think this issue comes more from writing the file name rather than opening the file it's just "noticed" there. Giving the file a different name is not an option.

**EDIT**

I have tried to create the variable `title_for_file` as a unicode string i.e. `u"{}".format(title)` but this did not work

Comment: Does your system allow that name at all? Like, can you name a file like that manually, without Python?

Comment: Which Python version is this? Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @KellyBundy you're right can't even have that filename!

Comment: @user202729 although I've found the solution Python 3.9.1, Windows

Comment: Please don't edit answers into questions. Feel free to post an answer and accept it if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kelly Bundy in the comments you can't actually name the file this.